# Emacs: Switching automatically to char-mode when switching to an ansi-term window

Tags: terminal, emacs

Say I have multiple windows open in Emacs **24.1** and that one of those windows is an `M-x ansi-term` window with a shell.

By default, when I switch to an ansi-term window, Emacs activates **Term: line run**, which prevents me from using keyboard shortcuts that work on the shell (e.g. tab completion, etc.).

Is there a way tell Emacs to automatically switch to **Term: char run** when I switch to a window in Emacs with an `ansi-term` terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line to your .emacs file.

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'char-line-mode)
```

Comment: I get the error `symbol's function definition is void: char-line-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816877/why-is-my-term-mode-hook-not-selecting-line-mode

"The road to getting ansi-term to work just like you want is woefully under-documented"